# How to write a C program for Unix that can process the Regular Expression ?

Tags: c, regex, unix, dfa

I want creat a C program for Unix that can porcess the Regular Expression,like a simple Perl interpreter. Do I have to personally write an regexp engine?

Comment: Have you done any research into regex with C, do you have some code to show us?

Comment: I can only write a simple lexical analyzer.

Comment: possible duplicate of [c regular expression howto](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1631450/c-regular-expression-howto)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

http://www.gnu.org/software/libc/manual/html_node/Regular-Expressions.html

You might like to look for a library with it already coded. C uses librarys to allow you to include other peoples code into your work. I assume there are many regular expression librarys for you to use already to go!

Comment: No prob! Happy coding! If you have a lot of stuff to code in C you may like to check out K&R or some other nice references, then just skim them over so you learn the rough idea of how the language works :).

Comment: I'm just a studious novice.Why those who belittle my question？I am so sad.But you are a good person.Thank you.

Comment: @fiigii : Don't forget to accept the answer that helps you solve your problem. The reputation points given to the user do not affect you reputation points. Good luck.