# Multiple hex ranges in c regex not working as expected

Tags: c, regex

I am trying to use C to match the following ranges of ASCII characters in hex: `\x21` / `\x23-\x2B` / `\x2D-\x39` / `\x3C-\x5B` / `\x5D-\x7E`

I have found this function matching regex in C on [another stack overflow answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1631450/c-regular-expression-howto):

```
int match(const char *string, char *pattern) {
    int status;
    regex_t regex;
    int d;
    if ((d = regcomp(&regex, pattern, REG_EXTENDED | REG_NOSUB)) != 0) {
      return 0;
    }

    status = regexec(&regex, string, (size_t)0, NULL, 0);
    regfree(&regex);
    if (status != 0) {
      return 0;
    }
    return (1);
}
```

This function will return 0 if the string does not match the given pattern and 1 if it does.

This function works for most patterns except for when I try to match multiple ranges of hex values.

For example:

```
int main(int argc, char const *argv[]) {
    printf("%d\n", match("HELLO!", "^[\x21 \x23-\x2B \x2D-\x39 \x3C-\x5B]+$")); // Matches as expected
    printf("%d\n", match("hello!", "^[\x21 \x23-\x2B \x2D-\x39 \x3C-\x5B]+$")); // Fails as expected because we are not including lower case letters
    printf("%d\n", match("HELLO!", "^[\x21 \x23-\x2B \x2D-\x39 \x3C-\x5B \x5D-\x7E]+$")); // Fails unexpectedly after adding 5D-7E
    printf("%d\n", match("hello!", "^[\x21 \x23-\x2B \x2D-\x39 \x3C-\x5B \x5D-\x7E]+$")); // Fails unexpectedly but should pass because we have added 5D-7E which includes lower case letters
    printf("%d\n", match("hello", "^[\x5D-\x7E]+$")); // Matches as expected because we have included lower case range
}
```

Which will output:

```
1 // Expected
0 // Expected
0 // Unexpected 
0 // Unexpected
1 // Expected
```

It seems that adding 5D-7E range to any other range breaks the regex expression.

Am I missing something or does this seem strange?

An ASCII table for reference can be seen [here](http://www.asciitable.com/index/asciifull.gif).

Comment: Don't use magic numbers! Why use magic value instead of the characters you want to match?

Comment: I could use the literal character of each of the values in the range but that line would be very long and tedious to type. Specifying the range of ascii characters I want is a more efficient way to do this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`\x5D` is a close bracket (<kbd>]</kbd>). That is to say, it really is a close bracket; the substitution is done before the program text is even parsed, as with all the rest of the backslash escapes. So your string

```
"^[\x21 \x23-\x2B \x2D-\x39 \x3C-\x5B \x5D-\x7E]+$"
```

is actually the string

```
"^[! #-+ --9 <-[ ]-~]+$"
```

and that is what `regcomp` compiles. [Note 1]

There are three problems with that pattern, one of which should be immediately obvious: the character class is terminated by the first <kbd>]</kbd>, so what is being matched is a single character which matches the character class `[! #-+ --9 <-[ ]`, followed literally by <kbd>-</kbd><kbd>~</kbd> and then followed by one or more <kbd>]</kbd> characters. Evidently, `HELLO!` does not match this pattern.

Secondly, the space character inside the character class is not special, which means that it is not ignored (as I believe you expect). As a consequence, the part of the character class which reads  `--9` actually means "any character between space (0x20) and dash (0x2D) or the character <kbd>9</kbd>".

Related to that, even if you removed the spaces (which you definitely need to do), `--9` would not be legal, because a <kbd>-</kbd> as a literal character can only appear at the beginning or end of a character class. [Note 2]

Finally, the character class `[\x5D-\x7E]` *does* do what you expect because a <kbd>]</kbd> is allowed to appear as a literal character if it is the first character in the character class, which in that case it is (`[]-~]`)

These rules are documented in the [regex manpage](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man7/regex.7.html) and in more detail in [Posix Base Definitions Section 9](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/basedefs/V1_chap09.html).

---

#### Notes:

1. You can provide a backslash as part of the regex string by backslash-escaping it (`"\\x5D"`) but that won't work with Posix regexes, because the Posix specification does not include hexadecimal escape sequences, nor the standard C escapes such as `\n`. As noted in the manpage, the Gnu C library regex implementation understands `\x` as a literal `x` and `\n` as a literal `n` (the same as a backslash followed by any alphabetic character). However, Posix does not define those usages; in a Posix Extended Regular Expression, backslash can only be used to escape special characters, and only outside of a character class.
2. Although the usage is undefined by the standard, it is possible that a regex library would recognize the `-` as a literal character because it appears immediately after a character range. However, it is poor practice to rely on extensions like this, even if they happen to work on a particular Posix library implementation.

Comment: Agreed. It is indeed clear to say it is done when the program text is parsed, long before the regular expression parser is run, which in C happens at runtime. A major difference from other programming languages such as Javascript that have regular expression literals.

Comment: @chqrlie: Languages definitely differ. In Python, for example, you can let the language convert escapes, or you can let the regex library do it, But Posix regular expressions are specified to perform a different set of backslash escape rules. Afaik, in C++ the interpretation of backslashes (literally inserted into the regex pattern) will differ depending on the regex flavour you specify. Bottom line: read the docs.

Comment: Thanks for your in depth answer! Given the limitations of Posix as pointed out in note 1, can I conclude that it is not possible to specify the hexadecimal ranges as I intend? Is there another way to do what I am trying to achieve without explicitly typing all of the literal characters I want to include?

Comment: @allanimals: I'd suggest specifying the characters you *don't* want to include: `[^\x01-\x20\x7F-\xFF\"\\,:;]`, if I got your intent right. That's a bit more readable, imho,

Comment: If you're using the C/Posix locale, the low ascii hex exclusions could be expressed with `[:cntrl:][:space:]`; Posix doesn't specify what category the high ascii codes fall into, so you would still need a hex escape for those, but it won't conflict with anything in the C character set. So you could also use: `[^[:cntrl:][:space:]\x80-\xFF\"\\,:;]`, which should work in most locales and will certainly work in the C locale. (Some legacy locales overlay control characters with graphical symbols, but I don't know if any of those are still in common use.)